# "Connect" UiTableView with NavigationController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am rather new to ios programming and i tried to create a tabbar application with 4 tabs
tab 1 and tab 2 are navigationcontrollers holding a UIView ... now i have a navigationbar, which i can access from my UIView classes.

I put a UITableView in the UIView-Class (with IB) and added a editbutton to the navigation bar:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

Ok, this seems easy and okay, but how can i connect the "edit button" with the uitableview in my UIView Class. The Table is filled with data but when i push the edit button nothing happens ... i do not want to change the UIView class to UITableView because ther are some other UI Elements on the View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend having a read of the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) (specifically the "Inserting and Deleting Rows in Editing Mode" section), as it covers everything you need and you'll learn a lot that'll stand you in good stead going forward.

Comment: Thanks you for the link ... here i found, that i have to override: --(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated

Comment: @gonzalesblanco Cool - glad you got it working in the end. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Got it! The `UIViewController` gets the editing message .. just override it and set the editing mode of the table within:

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
[self.myTableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];

}
```